# how to change data type from byte to list when pulling data from api

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

```
from requests import Session
import json
import pandas as pd

query = '''SELECT referring_domain, event_name FROM cooladata LIMIT  5000000;'''

def SQLtoURL(query):

    data = query.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t',' ').replace('   ',' ').replace('  ',' ')
    return data


def QueryCoola(query, file = None):

    session = Session()
    response = session.post(data = {'tq': query,'tqx': "out:csv",},
                              url =    'https://app.abcdefg.com/api/v2/projects/1111111/cql/', 
                              headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ****************'},)

    return response.text.encode('utf-8')



data = QueryCoola(SQLtoURL(query))
```

right now `data` type is in bytes, how do I get `data` in list or dictionary so I can then transfer it into a pandas dataframe?

What I'm currently doing is removing the `encode('utf-8')` so I get it in text and manually spliting it into a list that I can then move into a pandas data frame. the problem is with null values and so on I don't wanna keep handling these issues manually. Any help will be very much appreciated, thanks.

```
print(QueryCoola(SQLtoURL(query)))
```

OUTPUT:
b'"referring_domain"\n"www.google.com"\nnull\n"mood.reshet.tv"\n"m.facebook.com"\n"www.google.co.il"\nnull\nnull\n"www.google.com"\n"mood.reshet.tv"\n"www.google.com"\n'

Comment: Can you not `json.loads` it?

Comment: no, I tries. I think its only from string to list

Comment: Perhaps you should post a minimal example of what the data actually looks like?

Comment: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`

Comment: is what i wrote under OUTPUT not good enough? if so, what would you like me to post?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that.  Does the API support different formats for `tqx` (e.g. does it support `JSON`?)

Answer (score -1):

First of use `response.content` wich will give you the uninterpreted bytes requests received.

Do want to split the text on the newline character (`\n`) like

```
your_list = data.split("\n")
```

This will give you this output:

```
['"referring_domain"', '"www.google.com"', 'null', '"mood.reshet.tv"', ...]
```

You could remove the `'null'` values with:

```
your_list = filter(lambda a: a != "null", your_list)
```

and then remove the unnecessary `"` with:

```
your_list = [e[1:-1] for e in your_list]
```

wich will get you:

```
['referring_domain', 'www.google.com', 'mood.reshet.tv', 'm.facebook.com', 'www.google.co.il', 'www.google.com', 'mood.reshet.tv', 'www.google.com', '']
```

To remove the last empty (`''`) value filter the list again:

```
your_list = filter(lambda a: a != "", your_list)
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'result'`

Comment: But you can ignore "Second convert the bytes into a list like" as I did not understand your question at the time.